# Create image from ovf file at OpenStack using jcloud

Tags: openstack, occi, jclouds, openstack-nova

I've been reading http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/quickstart/openstack/ and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jclouds but I've not found any example to create an image from an OVF file in the OpenStack repository. Does anyone have any idea? I'd really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have an OVF file that you would like to import into an OpenStack cloud or do you already have an OVF image in an OpenStack cloud?

Comment: I have an OVF file that I'd like to import into an OpenStack cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be possible with jclouds as it doesn't support the Image service (aka Glance) API yet. You can [add a new image](http://docs.openstack.org/cli/quick-start/content/glance_client.html#glance-image-create) using the glance client though. You'll also want to look at this page about [container formats](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/glance/formats.html#container-format).

Whether or not this actually works may be dependent on your OpenStack deployment and choice of hypervisor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786156/is-it-possible-to-create-an-openstack-image-importing-an-ovf-file-with-glance