# Is it possible to create an OpenStack image importing an *.ovf file with Glance?

Tags: cloud, openstack, iaas

Is it possible to create an OpenStack image importing an ovf file with Glance?

EDIT_1: I'm interested on creating images just providing its ovf file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import an .ovf into Glance, but it does not currently have the ability to extract any data out of it.  Future releases may have this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

ovf seems to be supported.

check out all the image / container types here:

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/glance/formats.html

Comment: Thanks Matt. The links seems to show the supported format to store the running instances, but I'm interested on creating images just providing its ovf file (I've edited the question)